# Wordpress WPDB and Mysql strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using $wpdb and the following is part of the codes that calls $wpdb->update.

This code works well if it's normal email@domain.com, but when if users were to use the + sign in their username, e.g. email+something@domain.com, wpdb doesn't read the + sign

**Below variables are from $_GET but i'm putting in values for readability.**

```
$open_email = 'something+ADDITION@gmail.com';
$open_key = '2f1e4b16a9a882bbef9b00906fc5c8f563fd70a5';
$open_time = time();

if (strlen($open_key) == 40) {
    $status_update = $wpdb->update('status', 
            array(
                'invite_status' => 'opened',
                'open_time' => $open_time
                ),
            array(
                'invite_email' => $open_email,
                'invite_token' => $open_key
                ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%d'
                ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
                )
                );
}
```

var dump of $wpdb->last_query and $wpdb->last_error returns the followings.

string(235) "UPDATE `status` SET `invite_status` = 'opened', `open_time` = 1461103507 WHERE `invite_email` = '**something ADDITION@gmail.com**' AND `rating_invite_token` = '2f1e4b16a9a882bbef9b00906fc5c8f563fd70a5'"

I notice above part in error, highlighted in **bold**, that my plus (+) sign is gone and it left a space, causing the above statement not to update.

May I know am I missing out anything?

Update: I am asking because some users of gmails does use the + sign to categorise their emails, as username+anything@gmail.com still goes back to username@gmail.com

If there's any sanitisation which I am supposed to do, but i miss out, please guide me as well. I presume all $_GET data should have been sanitised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't `wpdb` or MySQL that's removing the plus.

Under the hood, when you call update like that, WordPress is passing the data through [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) and nothing else.

Since you mentioned the data is coming from the query string `$_GET`, most likely the `+` is being removed before the query because it us being unescaped and the `+` is being translated into a space.

You can check this with:

```
$open_email = $_GET['email'];
var_dump($open_email);
```

and see what the result is.

To get the plus back, it should be safe to do the following after all sanitzation and unescaping:

```
$open_email = str_replace(' ', '+', $open_email);
```

Comment: Oh yes, you are spot on! May I assume this is a common problem and str_replace(' ', '+',$open_email); is a common step to do after a GET with email string?

Comment: Yes and no, if you really want the `+` to be a plus, the URL should be hex encoded properly from the source, e.g. `http://example.com?email=something%2bADDITION%40gmail.com&open_key=xxx`  A `+` in a URL is special encoding for a space, if you want to actually represent a `+`, hex encode it as `%2b`